# Using AJAX to run django function from JS

Tags: javascript, django

I have a html button. when i press it i want to run a JS function that will call a django function. The website loads but when i press the button nothing happens. can anyone see where I am going wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<input type='button' value='run function' onclick='runScript()'>
```

**URLs.py:**

```
path('printing_function/', views.printing_function, name='printing_function')
```

**views.py:**

```
def printing_function(request):
    print("hello")
    return HttpResponse()
```

**Main.js:**

```
function runScript() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'print_function/',
        success: function(data) {
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: This could use more debugging details. What is the response to your ajax request?

Comment: In your urls.py, the url is **`printing_function/`** whereas in your ajax function, url is **`print_function/`**. **The urls don't match**. Also, in your html templates, start the urls with a slash (`/`), else you'll get into unexpected troubles. For more, read about relative and absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I use something like this :

```
function runScript() {
    // Add a log just to see if the function works
    console.log('button clicked!')
    $.get("{% url 'printing_function' %}")
        .done(function(response) {
            console.log(response)
        )
        .fail(function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        )
}
```

Note that `{% url ... %}` can only be used if you are in the HTML template. If you have isolated your JS in another file, you have to replace it with the exact url : `/printing_function/` (as pointing out by @xyres)

And in my view, I prefer to return a `JsonResponse` :

```
def printing_function(request):
    print("hello")
    return JsonResponse({'success': True})
```